# Taking var with JS prompt - how can I make it through HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been learning HTML/CSS/JavaScript for a couple of weeks now, and I am currently practicing on a mini project, which consists of letting people answer math questions, and validating their answers.

My current progress can be seen at http://dany.faceflow.com

I know I am probably not using the best strategy to develop this mini game, so any advice would be useful on that. However right now, the problem is that I am taking the user answer with a variable through JS prompt, and I want to do it via an HTML form (less annoying).

In my source code you can see this line within the function:

```
var userInput = prompt(numb1 + symbol + numb2);
```

Then, still in the same function, I have an if/else structure to compare the user's answer with the right answer. The code works, I just don't know how to make the prompt HTML-based instead. I've tried an html form with an ID and in the JS using getElementById, document.write and some other stuff but I never got it to work for that part.

(Here's all the JS)

```
var number1 = function() {
    var numb1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) + 10;
    return numb1;
}

var number2 = function() {
    var numb2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) + 10;
    return numb2;
}


var userAnswer = function() {
    var numb1 = number1();
    var numb2 = number2();

    var randomSymbol = Math.random();

    if (randomSymbol > 0.5)  {
        var symbol = "+";
    } else {
        var symbol = "-";
    }

    // add the math question in the html bubble
    document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = numb1 + symbol + numb2;

    // Prompts the user to give an answer. Change this to HTML.
    var userInput = prompt(numb1 + symbol + numb2);

    //var userInput = document.getElementById('tw').value;


    if (symbol == "+" && userInput == (numb1 + numb2)) {
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Congratulations!";
    } else if (symbol == "+" && userInput !== (numb1 + numb2)) {
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Wrong!";
    } else if (symbol == "-" && userInput == (numb1 - numb2)) {
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Congratulations!";
    } else if (symbol == "-" && userInput !== (numb1 - numb2)) {
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Wrong!";
    } else {
        alert("Something wrong happened. Try again.");
    }

    return userInput;
}
```

(The HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <title>Improve Your Math Skills!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>

        <button onclick="userAnswer()">PLAY NOW!</button>

        <div id="bubble"></div>

        <div id="feedback"></div>


        <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> -->
        </center>
    </body>     
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `input` tag instead of the prompt. Change the HTML just as in Dinesh's answer;

```
<div id="bubble"></div>
<div id="inp" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="ans"></input>&nbsp;<button id="subBtn">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Now, for the JavaScript, there a few things to consider. Firstly, you have

```
var number1 = function() {
    var numb1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) + 10;
    return numb1;
}

var number2 = function() {
    var numb2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) + 10;
    return numb2;
}
```

Both functions do exactly the same thing; you don't need two separate functions to get two separate random numbers. So, only one function will suffice.

```
var number = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) + 10;
};
```

Secondly, now we have two functions. `userAnswer` to post a new question when 'Play Now!' is clicked and, say, `evalAnswer` to evaluate the answer written in the input field when 'Submit' is clicked.

In `userAnswer`, you generate two new random numbers and figure out which operation will be conducted on them. At this point, you can simply evaluate the answer yourself and store it in a global variable. This makes things easier when you evaluate the answer, you only need to do a simple comparison.

Other than that, you update `innerHTML` for `bubble` and display the `div` `inp`.

In `evalAnswer`, you get the value from `ans` and compare it with the previously computed value of the current answer, and then accordingly update `feedback.innerHTML`.

Here's the code;

```
//variable to maintain the current answer
var curAns = 0;

//Here, I get all the DOMElements I will use 
var playBtn = document.getElementById('playBtn');

var bubble = document.getElementById('bubble');

var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var ans = document.getElementById('ans');
var subBtn = document.getElementById('subBtn');

var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

//I add the event listeners
//This is equivalent to using 'onclick'
//in the HTML, and doing it this way is only
//my personal preference
playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {userAnswer();}, false);
subBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {evalAnswer();}, false);

//Function to get random number
var number = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) + 10;
};

//This function will be executed when 'Play Now!' is clicked.
var userAnswer = function() {
    //Get two separate random numbers in
    //numb1 and numb2
    var numb1 = number();
    var numb2 = number();
    var symbol = '';

    var randomSymbol = Math.random();

    //Determine the operation to be used
    //and compute the corresponding correct answer for the current
    //question
    if (randomSymbol > 0.5)  {
        symbol = "+";
        curAns = numb1+numb2;
    } else {
        symbol = "-";
        curAns = numb1-numb2;
    }

    //Add math question to bubble
    bubble.innerHTML = 'What is ' + numb1 + ' ' + symbol + ' ' + numb2 + '?';
    feedback.innerHTML = '';

    //Make inp div visible
    inp.style.display = 'block';
    //Reset input value to ''
    ans.value = '';
};

//This function will be executed when 'Submit' is clicked
var evalAnswer = function() {
    //Simply compare input value with computed
    //answer and update feedback 
    if(parseInt(ans.value) !== curAns) {
        feedback.innerHTML = 'Wrong answer, try again!';
    }
    else {
        feedback.innerHTML = 'You got it right, congratulations!';
    }
};
```

**[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tF9Ps/)**.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  As a beginner that's exactly the kind of thing that will make me improve quickly. I can spot a lot of mistakes I've made which I can now rectify for the future. I'll keep on building the game ;) Thanks again, very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you need the same functionality in HTML itself rather than driven by JS in a prompt box, if so,the below additions to your code should help:

HTML adition:

```
<div id="bubble"></div>
<div id="check_ans_div" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" id="txt_answer" />
  <input type="submit" value="Check Answer" onclick="checkanswer()" />
</div>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

JS changes:

```
    var number1 = function() {
        var numbx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) + 10;
        return numbx;
    }        
    var number2 = function() {
        var numby = Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) + 10;
        return numby;
    }
    var numb1=0; var numb2=0;
    var userAnswer = function() {
       numb1 = number1();
       numb2 = number2();

        var randomSymbol = Math.random();

        if (randomSymbol > 0.5)  {
            var symbol = "+";
        } else {
            var symbol = "-";
        }

        // add the math question in the html bubble
        document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML = numb1 + symbol + numb2;
        if(document.getElementById('check_ans_div').style.display=='none') 
           document.getElementById('check_ans_div').style.display='block'; 
        document.getElementById('txt_answer').value='';

    }

function checkanswer(){

      var userInput= document.getElementById('txt_answer').value;
      if (symbol == "+" && userInput == (numb1 + numb2)) {
            document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Congratulations!";
        } else if (symbol == "+" && userInput !== (numb1 + numb2)) {
            document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Wrong!";
        } else if (symbol == "-" && userInput == (numb1 - numb2)) {
            document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Congratulations!";
        } else if (symbol == "-" && userInput !== (numb1 - numb2)) {
            document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Wrong!";
        } else {
            alert("Something wrong happened. Try again.");
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me. When trying your code, I got problems about "symbol" and "numb1" "numb2" not being defined. I think I may have to think of a plan and re-build the program and apply what I learned from you (HTML form working with JS)

Comment: Ah! You are correct, the numb1 and numb2 needs to be declared outside those functions, updated my code, should work now. And its good to restructure the code well, since you are learning, it would be good idea to redo it :)